# useEffect with map to show a different color for an icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

First of all, I am just a beginner learning React so bare with me.

I am trying to display an icon with different color if it fits a condition. I know I have to use useEffect and also the map method. But I don't get to develop it the right way. This is what I have:

```
export const PreloadCard = ({ preload }) => {

  const { favorites } = useSelector( state => state.favorites );
  

  const favoriteIconColor = useEffect(() => {
    favorites.map( favorite => {
      if ( favorite.preloadID.includes(preload.preloadID) )
      return () => {
        "error"
      }
    })
  }, [favorites])
  
  return (
    <List>
      
       <Card>
        <CardHeader
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon color= { favoriteIconColor }/>
            </IconButton>
          }
          titleTypographyProps={{ variant:'h7' }}
          title={ preload.name }
          subheader={ preload.artist }
        />
)}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `useEffect` returns `undefined` ... what does `favourites` hold and what you are trying to do here ?

Comment: you should read more about useEffect but also about useState, I think you should use useState here

Comment: This seems like the wrong use of useEffect here. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your expected behaviour but I'll assume 'error' is a colour

You don't need `useEffect` if anything you should use `useMemo` -

```
const favoriteIconColor = useMemo(() =>
   favorites.some(favorite => favorite.preloadID.includes(preload.preloadID)) ? 'error' : undefined 
, [favorites, preload])
```

Will give you a colour of 'error' if preloadID matches, else undefined. Feel free to amend as necessary

p.s. apologies for poor formatting, I'm on my phone

Comment: I am sorry my question was not specific enough. Even though I didn't formulate it correctly, you have given the right answer. As I said I am just learning and obviously I need to review the useMemo and useEffect hook. Sorry about that! And thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using useEffect you should calculate color before the return statement. Read more about useEffect at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
export const PreloadCard = ({ preload }) => {
  const { favorites } = useSelector((state) => state.favorites);

  let favoriteIconColor = '';
  favorites.every((favorite) => {
    if (favorite.preloadID.includes(preload.preloadID)) {
      favoriteIconColor = 'error';
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });

  return (
    <List>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          action={
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon color={favoriteIconColor} />
            </IconButton>
          }
          titleTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h7' }}
          title={preload.name}
          subheader={preload.artist}
        />
      </Card>
    </List>
  );
};
```

Comment: In order to do this `favoriteIconColor` must be declared with `let`.